# Configure useAsynSend in jmsTemplate with JNDI

Tags: spring-jms, jmstemplate

I am using jmsTemplate with the below spring configuration [ using "*****" to conceal structure ].

I want to configure useAsyncSend=true in this configuration so that the jmsTemplate will not wait for ack from broker. I am not sure on how to go about doing that with JNDI - could anyone please assist on how best to do it?

```
<bean id="jndiTemplate" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate">
        <property name="environment">
            <props>
                <prop key="java.naming.factory.initial">weblogic.jndi.WLInitialContextFactory</prop>
                <prop key="java.naming.provider.url">${*****.application.jnditemplate.java.naming.provider.url}</prop>
                <prop key="java.naming.security.principal">${*****.application.jnditemplate.java.naming.security.principal}</prop>                   
                <prop key="java.naming.security.credentials">${*****.application.jnditemplate.java.naming.security.credentials}</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean> 

     <bean id="queueConnectionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
        <property name="jndiTemplate">
            <ref bean="jndiTemplate" />
        </property>
        <property name="jndiName">
            <value>com.*****.jms.connectionFactory</value>
        </property>
    </bean> 

     <bean id="jmsDestinationResolver"
        class="org.springframework.jms.support.destination.JndiDestinationResolver">
        <property name="jndiTemplate">
            <ref bean="jndiTemplate" />
        </property>
        <property name="cache">
            <value>true</value>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="jmsTemplate" class="org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate">
        <property name="connectionFactory">
            <ref bean="queueConnectionFactory" />
        </property>
        <property name="destinationResolver">
            <ref bean="jmsDestinationResolver" />
        </property>
        <property name="sessionAcknowledgeMode">
        <value>2</value>
        </property>     
    </bean>
```

Comment: http://activemq.2283324.n4.nabble.com/How-to-check-if-jms-useAsyncSend-true-is-set-in-an-inbound-message-td4672842.html

Comment: http://chriswongdevblog.blogspot.co.il/2013/01/jmstemplate-is-not-evil.html